# Using fgets for input in C

Tags: c, fgets

I'm trying to use fgets in a function to obtain input in C. My code displays properly, however it does not follow my parameters for the do/while loop (if I enter a number outside of the range, it proceeds with the program, rather than repeating the loop until the input is proper). I have tried tinkering with it, and I can't figure out what my issue is. I think it might have something to do with it taking the input as a character and not as an integer. But I tried casting my entry variable into an int, and that was no help. Any assistance is greatly appreciated!

```
{
 char  line[MAX_LINE];

 int   entry;

    do
    {
     printf("Please enter %s(%d-%d) ", descriptionCPtr, low, high);
     fgets(line, MAX_LINE, stdin);
     entry = (int)line[0];
    }

    while(entry < low || entry > high);
    return(entry);
}
```

Comment: Have you done any basic debugging? Such as using a debugger or printing out the `line` and `entry` values? Surely you can find out more about the problem before asking for help.

Comment: Yes. I printed my entry value and it keeps giving me a "45" or a "52". Not sure where it is coming from, and line gives me 119054520.

Comment: Well, then why didn't you provide that info and ask about that rather than the `while` loop? Because clearly `entry` is not what you expect and that is the initial point of failure. I suggest you review what casting does. It can not turn a string into its `int` equivalent. Then look up [atoi](https://linux.die.net/man/3/atoi).

Comment: Never use a cast if you are not 100% sure what it does! Without any offence, but your apparently don't know what casts are for. Briefly: casts are not for string to numerical conversion. That in mind, the rest should be easy to find.

Comment: better to check the return code from fgets, like this: `if ( fgets (line, MAX_LINE, stdin) != NULL )`

Comment: did you know that 45 is the ascii code for the `-` character and 52 is the ascii code for the `4` character?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your intuition is correct. You are not properly converting user input to a numeric value. `fgets` reads user input and stores it (along with `\n`) into `line` variable; an array of characters. Let's assume the user is an old man entering his age `99`, so `line` will be an array of `9`, `9`, `\n` and `\0` characters. In the next line however, you are casting `line[0]` which is character `9` (with ASCII code 57) into an integer and assigning 57 to `entry`. Well, this probably is not what you intend to achieve here.

My recommended solution for this case is to use `scanf` instead of `fgets`.

```
int age;

scanf("%d", &age);
if (age < min_age || age > max_age)
    printf("age not valid\n");
```

In case you want to stick with fgets, you can remove the new line character and replace casting with calling functions like `atoi` (which is not really safe by the way) to convert `line` into integer.